# XF Library references conflict with each other

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I have upgraded one of my XamarinForms Class library projects to **.NetStandard2.0** and now when I add the nuget package to my other **.NetStandard2.0** project it does not let me compile it and shows me some 8000 errors like this one:

```
/Volumes/Data/Projects/Project1App copy/Project1/Project1.Android/CSC: Error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: '/Users/drtj/.nuget/packages/royalxamarincomponents/1.1.3/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll' and '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. (CS1703) (Project1.Android)
```

or this

```
/Volumes/Data/Projects/Project1App copy/Project1/Project1.Android/CSC: Error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: '/Users/drtj/.nuget/packages/royalxamarincomponents/1.1.3/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Threading.dll' and '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Threading.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. (CS1703) (Project1.Android)
```

Comment: Is `royalxamarincomponents` library necessary for your project? If not, removing it should resolve the conflict

Comment: This is the library I'm trying to add

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your project's `.csproj` file and add below codes into the `<ItemGroup>`.

```
<PackageReference Include="RoyalXamarinComponents" Version="1.1.3" >
     <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```